# ImportError: No module named C:Python27Libsite-packagesSelenium2Library

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I am trying to run a simple test case (opening the browser with specified URL) using RIDE.

I gave the Selenium2Library path as --> C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\Selenium2Library\
(Note: It was appeared in Red Color).

I wrote the Test Case by giving below keywords.

```
open browser http://www.google.com ie
```

When I ran the above Test Case, I got the below error. Could someone please help me how to resolve this issue?

```
[ ERROR ] Error in file 'D:\Test1.txt': Importing test library 'C:Python27Libsite-packagesSelenium2Library' failed: ImportError: No module named C:Python27Libsite-packagesSelenium2Library
```

***Note:*** I have RIDE 1.2.3, Robot Framework 2.8.4, Python 2.7.6.

Comment: Looks like you should have used double backslashes for the library path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved the problem, by specifying the Library path in **double back slashes (\\)** OR **forward slash (/)**, as like below.

> C:\\Python27\\Lib\\site-packages\\Selenium2Library\\
>   **OR**     C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages/Selenium2Library/.

Comment: Selenium2Library like all the other libraries in site-packages can be imported by just specifying the libray name, like this `Library    Selenium2Library`